# PHP 2 people logging in at the same time from the same computer

Tags: php, mysql, login-script

I have a login script that should check for 2 people login in at the same time it compares the usernames and the password in the mysql server if the user exists

```
//Player 1 Login username and password
$p1name = $_POST['p1name'];
$p1pass = $_POST['p1pass'];

//player 2 Login username and password
$p2name = $_POST['p2name'];
$p2pass = $_POST['p2pass'];






$connection = mysql_connect("db_host", "db_user", "db_pass");
mysql_select_db("db_name", $connection);





 get_user($p1name, $p1pass);
 get_user($p2name, $p2pass);

$row = $result;
$found = false;

    if(($row["username"] == $p1name && $row["password"] == sha1("$p1pass")) && ($row["username"] == $p2name && $row["password"] == sha1("$p2pass"))){
            $found = true;
            break;
        }


function get_user($username, $password) {
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM users';
    $query .= ' WHERE username = ' . mysql_real_escape_string($username);
    $query .= ' AND password = ' . mysql_real_escape_string(sha1($password));
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    return mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to handle this?

Comment: is for a game two players login from the same computer at the same time to start the game

Comment: it's a loop - that's what's wrong with it.

Comment: so i remove the while lopp and just have the if statement and have $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) before the if statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You're using `=` instead of `===` (or, if you must, `==`).  `=` is the assignment operator in PHP; `===` and `==` are equality operators.
2. You're comparing the same username to both `$p1name` and `$p2name`.  Unless those two variables are the same, the expression (after correcting (1) above) will never evaluate to `true`.
3. You're looping instead of using SQL to loop for you.  For example:

   ```
   function get_user($username, $password) {
       $query = 'SELECT * FROM users';
       $query .= ' WHERE username = ' . mysql_real_escape_string($username);
       $query .= ' AND password = ' . mysql_real_escape_string(sha1($password));
       $result = mysql_query($query);
       return mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    }
   ```

As for knowing when two people "on the same computer" are trying to join the same game (or whatever), it's common to instead to provide a *game ID*.  Users can then join a game by connecting using that game ID, often by accessing a certain URL.

After a user logs in, they'll be given the option to start a game.  When they do, provide the game ID in the URL as a GET parameter (e.g. `mysite/game.php?gameid=2153259`).  (You may want to use random ID's or something for the game ID to prevent other players from joining the game "accidentally".)  The "host" can then give the URL to someone else, and then the new user is entered into the game (perhaps after being asked).

Comment: 3. Nothing in your condition is checking for the same computer

Comment: the variables are diferrent two login forms two username and two different passwords coming from the smae .html

Comment: @hgbso, Do you intend to grab both users (as e.g. `$p1user` and `$p2user`)?  If so, I'll update my example.

Comment: yes both user to see f the login they provided are the same in the mysql table

Comment: bothe user login from a form in a separate .html then sent to a .php scipt for login/check

Comment: the game starts automatically when the players login in the same script as the game and do i set a session id when once the players have been logged in

Comment: do i out this function before the if statement in my post

Comment: do i put this function before the if statement

Answer (score 1):

I would use a query to check user name and password against such a table all in one go, not by getting the table,looping through and testing each field.

What if you have 100,000 users using your method? it would be slow,inefficient and what if someone changes their password whilst your script is chugging through 100,000 users checking them? they would be able to log on to more machines because the machines checking would already have old data in memory.

If you are only allowed to login to one computer and this stays true you could add login/logoff timestamps, status and a computer name fields to manage the rest. Personally i would keep that data separate table.

But i think you should also ask yourself how your going to deal with logoff's and logoff time-outs.

Comment: "I would use a query to check user name and password against such a table all in one go, not by getting the table,looping through and testing each field." like the post strager made

Comment: i forgot to mention the users are logging into a sessions

Answer (score 0):

On the users table, have two fields, one to specify if is logged in, and another that specifies the ip used to login.

When the user logs in, also save that information to a session variable.

Then, when a user does some action on the game, compare what is in the session to what is on the database. If it is different, then the user has logged in in another computer, and you should log him out from the current location.

To check if multiple users are using the same computer, check the ip they used to log in. Of course they could be behing a nat or a proxy, in which case you could just prevent interactions between players with the same ip instead of banning them / loggin them out.